# Scaling a Visio Shape with Connections (connection scaling)

Tags: microsoft-visio, diagrams

**Is it possible to scale the connections along with a shape without having to "rewire" everything?**

I'm trying to resize a Diagramm with many connection lines that are sorted, but when resizing the diagramm the connection lines stay the same, thus need to be adjusted individually, and that's basically redoing all the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I've tried it and there doesn't seem to be a proper solution **inside visio**.

However, if it's for printing purposes or simply better viewing, it is possible to select all (**CTRL+A**) and then

go to File > Export > Other Filetype > Choose **PNG** and save it

Quality settings can be adjusted to your liking.
The PNG File then can be "easier" resized by something like *Irfanviewer* or similar.

Comment: Please correct me if I've missed something in Visio, I would appreciate the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no proper way to scale the connectors **inside** the Visio. But exporting the figure in PNG format may be neither a proper way. PNG is not a Vector Diagram format actually.

A workaround is to open PPT aside, copy the diagram directly to a slide in PowerPoint and paste it back to the Visio. It remains the vector diagram format and can scale as a normal shape as well.